# Suppose $a$ is a positive real number such that $a^5-a^3+a=2$. Then find range of $a^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $a$ is a positive real number such that $a^5-a^3+a=2$. Then find range of $a^6$.

The answer given to the question is $3<a^6<4$ .

I attempted solving the question by multiplying with $a^2$ on both sides to get 
$a^7=a^5-a^3+2a^2$ = $2-a + 2a^2 $.

And then I am not able to proceed please help me out with this problem

Comment: What does the question even mean? The equation $a^5-a^3+a=2$ uniquely identifies $a= 1.205569430...$ as the only positive real root. So $a^6$ is uniquely known. What "range" is there to speak of?

Comment: It was given a competitive exam where students where not allowed to use a calculator therefore they probably asked a range

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the question makes no sense. What would make sense is something like "prove that $3<a^6<4$, where $a$ is a positive real number that satisfies $a^5-a^3+a=2$". As stated, there is no unique solution to the problem!

Comment: ... Well, if $a = 1.205569430... $ then $3 < a^6< 4$.  But that is the "the range".  That is $a^6$ within the nearest integer.  You can get a tighter range, such as $3.07 < a^6 < 3.08$ if you want.

Comment: If the asked "find the range between two consecutive integers so that $a^6$ is in the range" I think this would be legitimate.  Maybe... could be worded better..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the suggestion of fleablood, I'm going to assume the question asks you to find the integer $n$ so that $n<a^6<n+1$. You already obtained
$$a^7=2a^2-a+2,$$
so we divide through on both sides by $a$ to get
$$a^6=2a-1+\frac2a.$$
Since $a$ is positive, we may use the AM-GM inequality to get:
$$a^6=\left(2a+\frac2a\right)-1>2\sqrt{4}-1=3.$$
Note that the inequality is strict because $a\neq 1$. To show that $a^6<4$ is a bit harder. Note that the function $f(a)=a^5-a^3+a$ is a monotonically increasing function (if you know calculus, prove this by showing the derivative is everywhere positive). Furthermore you can check that $f(\sqrt[6]4)=f(\sqrt[3]2)$ is greater than $2$, so that the value of $a$ satisfying $f(a)=2$ must be less than $\sqrt[6]4$. In other words, $a^6<4$.

Comment: Thank you got it

Comment: Still easier: One can easily check that $1\le a\le 2$, on that interval $a+\frac1a$ is monotonous, so that $a^6\in [2-1+2, 4-1+1]=[3,4]$.

Answer (score 2):

Given that  $a^5 - a^3 + a=2$ we write $$a^3\left(a^2-1+\frac{1}{a}\right)=2$$
This implies $$a^3\left(\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^2-3\right)=2$$
Now by A.M-G.M inequality $a+\frac{1}{a}\gt 2$. Now using this we can write $\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^2\gt 4$. Therefore,$$a^3(4-3)\lt a^3\left(\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^2-3\right)=2\implies a^3\lt 2\implies a^6\lt 4$$

Comment: $a+\frac{1}{a}\gt 2 $ as equality occurs  when $a=\frac{1}{a}$ this forces $a=1$ and it can be easily checked that $a=1$ does not satisfy the original equation.

Comment: $a^6\gt 3$ part is still remaining....

Comment: Together with the first part of my answer this gives a complete elementary solution to the problem (without calculus). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you yifan.... I'm still at it

Comment: @ Rishabh shetty, you have your solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the noble help @ HVxvejjw and @ YiFan

Comment: @Rishabh shetty  then upvote my answer...haha

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* No, multiply through by $a$ instead, and with a little rearrangement, you now have $$a^6=a^4-a^2+2a,$$ whose right hand side is a biquadratic in $a.$ You may still attempt to complete squares on RHS.

Comment: Isn't it $2a$ instead of $2$

Comment: @RishabhShetty Oh, yes, it is. An oversight from here. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how completing squares helps. We get $a^4-a^2+2a=(a^2-1/2)^2+2a-1/4$, what do we do then? How to deal with the $2a-1/4$?

Comment: Yes I am to facing the same problem